# Why didn't Yoda and Kenobi look for Windu?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

In *Star Wars: Revenge of Sith*, after watching the security hologram, Yoda and Kenobi would have come to know what happened to Windu. But following from [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12890/is-it-possible-that-mace-windu-survived-his-encounter-with-sidious), it was still a possibility that Windu could have survived. After all, he was a very powerful Jedi.

Why didn't they search for Windu's body? They could have even saved him if he was fighting with death. And then it'd have been easier for them to kill Sidious.

Comment: They know that [Samuel L. Jackson Dies](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5kYY_C3334U&feature=watch_response) in [A Lot of Movies](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=-Dbu02_pdGw), so it would be pointless to search for him.

Comment: He fell victim to a pit.  There is no coming back once a Jedi falls into a pit.

Comment: They were in a hurry to first destroy the Sith then flee...

Comment: @Jeff unless it's a Rancor pit.

Comment: @MichaelItzoe: Ah, but once he hit the floor it stopped being a pit and became a room - he saw the door.  No more rancor.

Comment: If into the pit you fall, then come back you will not, mmmmmm.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Master Windu was strong in the force and his death would have been [felt through the force](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_sense).  So there would have been no reason for Yoda or Obi-wan to go look for the body.  Especially since the Jedi were being slaughtered through order 66 so the investigation would have put the masters at further risk.

The movies only show important scenes.  I would assume that someone had found Windu's remains.  [Coruscant](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Coruscant)(the planet where this scene takes place) is fully urbanized with the vast majority of the surface being covered in [duracrete](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Permacrete).  The [Republic Executive Building](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Republic_Executive_Building) where the action takes place is described as being several kilometers above the  surface.    Seeing as he fell from near the top of the building I do not think that his remains would have been something that could be shown in a PG movie even had there been time for an investigation of the site.

Comment: Episode 3 was Pg-13 I believe, maybe that means they could show his arm...

Comment: I upvoted you because I don't know why I liked your answer. But, can you pinpoint `Death Feeling` as a power of force user? Any reference?

Comment: @SachinShekhar - make that a separate Q :)

Comment: @Chad there's typo in my name.. you should use auto-complete. Anyway, please expand that force application. Still don't get what's the force disturbance difference arises due to unconsious and dead Jedi..

Comment: @DVK Looks like there's really need of it.. :)

Comment: @SachinShekhar - Yes make that a different question.  I think it is a good one worthy of its own answer.

Comment: @Chad Even if he hit terminal velocity, there are instances of people surviving falls from several miles...certainly no part of him would "look like stew".

Comment: @Chad Hey, that's introduced by you. I am even not sure that question would repel downvotes or not.. Atleast, you can show this thing really exists, then I could ask its reason..

Comment: @SachinShekhar - There is plenty of canon supporting it.  Luke knew when his wife died on a far away planet as did Leia and her daughter despite there being no holo recording.  That is just a single instance.  Jedi have a bad habit of dieing throughout the EU.

Comment: @Chad Luke's wife? Sounds like you've stepped into EU. Now, I can't proceed as I haven't read those novels.. :) Anyway, thanks for the answer..

Comment: @SachinShekhar - Yes and because of topic its almost impossible to discuss with out alot of spoilers.  But I could give you 9 of them just off the top of my head with out a lot of thought.

Comment: @SachinShekhar - There are various examples of rippling disturbances in the force in reaction to significant events. Examples: destruction of Alderaan, Anakin's murder of the tuskan raiders, Order 66. They don't necessarily know what the cause is, but sometimes, as with Anakin and the Tuskans, there *appears* to be some ability to relate to the individual cause (Yoda's discussion with Windu that followed). It's possible Mace's death could have been one of these instances, however there's no compelling evidence; there is no exposition and events appeared 'business as usual.' All speculative.

Comment: Assuming he was alive when he fell, why did he not grab a ride like Anakin did in Episode 2?

Comment: @Raphael - I Think he landed on a plane... but it was filled with snakes.

Answer (score 1):

Others are on to something when they mention that death can be felt through the Force, but Disney canon has given us the specific example in TLJ where Rey and Leia are both able to feel the death of

> Luke

via the Force. Rey and Leia are, at this point, not necessarily full Jedi (Leia almost certainly isn't, and it's unclear if Rey is or not), so, if even they can sense a death this way, it stands to reason that Yoda and Kenobi (who had full Jedi training) could have felt the death of Windu and known not to go looking for him.

Comment: Note that Leia also apparently felt the death of Han, so it's not even necessarily confined to when a force user dies: it could just be somebody you have a long term attachment to.